# Why Python tries to compute some calculations in multiprocessing in advance

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit with processor-Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 and 16gb of RAM.
So when I run this program, it uses a single core instead of using all the 4 cores.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def boom1(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)

def boom2(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)   

def boom3(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)   

def boom4(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)

if __name__=="__main__":
    array = []
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom1, args=(array,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom2, args=(array,))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom3, args=(array,))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom4, args=(array,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()


    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

    print('Done')
```

Now if I print some low power of 10 in each function:

```
print(5 ** 10000000)
```

Now for small duration of time, a single core is processing 100% and then all 4 cores are performing 100%.
Why is this so? Shouldn't it start with all cores performing 100%.

What I had come to know was that python performs some operation before itself and hence was doing that from a single core. If it is so then what is the point of python being an interpreted language or am I missing something?does

Answer (score 2):

The peephole optimizer is trying to constant-fold the `5**10000000000` calculation. This happens before any worker processes launch.

Answer (score 2):

Most languages have a constant-folding optimization: when an operation between constants appears, the compiler will perform the operation and replace the expression with the single-constant result.

Python does this, as well.  I expect that your multi-node operation was simply the sequence of start-print-join on each node.

If you want to get longer runs on the four nodes, try an expression that can't be evaluated at parse-time.  For instance, pass the base in the argument list and use that instead of 5, or perhaps have each process pick a random number in the range 1-10 and add that to the exponent.  This should force run-time evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the previous answers are correct, but may not fully explain your observations.  As others have pointed out, that the single processor time you're seeing is the time that the interpreter is spending to calculate the value of the exponential expression.  Because you're using integers, and Python can do arbitrarily long integers, this takes quite awhile, probably exponential in terms of the number of 0's in your exponent.  In the first case, the calculation is taking so long that it appears to not get past that (I don't know if you ran to completion, or if your machine could even do it without running out of memory).

In the second case, you've removed enough zeros so that it can calculate it (single threaded interpreter) then proceed to print it (in parallel).  However long that took, it will probably take at least 1000 times longer to do the first case.